# Ignoring code scanning alerts on PR that have been dismissed on default branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I have enabled a couple of different code scanning tools in my GitHub Actions workflow that each upload their results to the GitHub Security tab (via upload-sarif).

One of these scans produces a lot of alerts that are not relevant for my project, as it scans the built container image and produces alerts for all of the packages and utilities included in the base (Linux) image regardless of whether they are used by my application. So I have reviewed all of the alerts on the GitHub Security tab and dismissed (as "Won't Fix") the alerts that are not relevant.

Subsequent executions of the GitHub Actions workflow on the default branch work fine - the code scanning tool still generates all of the alerts, but GitHub sees that the alerts have already been dismissed and doesn't add or re-open them on the Security tab.

However, I also want to run the scan on PRs targeting my default branch in order to catch any new alerts before they are merged. But here GitHub doesn't appear to be checking that the alerts have already been dismissed on the default branch, so the code scanning check fails on every PR. Worse, if I ignore the check and merge the PR anyway, the alerts are transferred over to the default branch and need to be manually dismissed again.

Is there a workaround for this, or should I be approaching this in a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the code scanning tool in question (Trivy) does not include fingerprints in its SARIF output, which is what confuses GitHub. I've made a feature request for Trivy here: https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy/issues/1840

As a workaround, I've discovered that keeping the container image name static for code scanning allows GitHub's fallback deduplication logic to correctly identify duplicate alerts.